# Loading Azure maps - It flashes the whole world first then it sets camera to its position

Tags: azure-maps

In depth issue -
When a user loads Map Page it initially loads a map of the whole world before quickly loading just the map portion required.

Goal - **What i want is to direct moves to my desired location instead of flashing the whole world first.**

Cause - As per my knowledge, this is caused due to following code -

```
this.maper.events.add('ready', () => { })
```

But the above code is required too as all the other necessary actions are to be done inside this function only once map gets ready.

Please guide me how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

Set the map camera options when loading the map rather than after the map is loaded. For example:

```
map = new atlas.Map('myMap', {
    center: [-110, 50],
    zoom: 2,
    view: 'Auto',
    
    authOptions: {
        authType: 'subscriptionKey',
        subscriptionKey: '<Your Azure Maps Key>'
    }
});
```

Comment: this is working but now map seems a bit shakky!.. because from your code i have set it to center and zoom level but when map gets ready then originally i have got different co-ordinates so map gets shaky from one center to another.

Comment: Use the center/zoom values you want for the initial map view in there. If you use different values after the map is loaded, of course it is going to move.